# VBA Excel copy text file to worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy, text-files

I'm trying to take statistics of a specific column in a text file and I thought the best way to do it might be to copy all contents from the text file into an excel worksheet and then count it from there (otherwise I would need to try and read only that one line directly from the excel file).  Here's the code of what I have so far:

```
Dim filePath As String
Dim currentValue As String
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long
Dim badAddress As Long
Dim coverageNoListing As Long
Dim activeListing As Long
Dim noCoverageNoListing As Long
Dim inactiveListing As Long
Dim fso As Object
Dim f As Object

'' filePath would include entire file name (picked from a browser button)
filePath = ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Text

'' Makes sure there isn't a sheet named "Temp_Text_File"
For Each testSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If testSheet.Name Like "Temp_Text_File" Then flag = True: Exit For
Next

'' If there is a sheet named "Temp_Text_File" it will be deleted
If flag = True Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp_Text_File").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If

'' Recreate sheet
Sheets.Add.Name = "Temp_Text_File"
'' Here I would want to copy everything (similar to manually doing "Ctrl+A" then "Ctrl+C") from the text file

'' Then paste into worksheet (similar to manually doing "Ctrl+V") within this created worksheet range("A1")

'' Delete at the end (user has no need for it)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp_Text_File").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Thank you,

Jesse Smothermon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am doing a similar thing, here is my sub for this:

I open a txt file with `|` as separator. Then copy the content of the sheet to my destination workbook (global variable). Then I close the first workbook that contains the original txt file without saving.

The code for the Workbooks.OpenText is basically from recording a macro and adapting it to my needs.

```
Sub ImportTextFile(path As String)
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim TMPWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim TxtFilePath As String
    Dim TxtFileName As String

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook

    SheetName = "Test_Result"
    TxtFileName = path & "file.txt"

    Workbooks.OpenText FileName:= _
        TxtFileName _
        , Origin:=437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
        xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), _
        Array(2, 1)), DecimalSeparator:=".", ThousandsSeparator:=",", _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    Set TMPWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    TMPWorkBook.Sheets("file").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy

    ResultWB.Activate

    ResultWB.Sheets(SheetName).Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    TMPWorkBook.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Alright totally, I see both the copy and the paste that I did and your code is probably better since other people using these can change the code slightly to meet their needs better than they could with mine.  Thank you for the response

Answer (score 1):

I found a bit of code that does the copying and it seems to be correct (only tested once though, sorry)

Sorry for posting this question, it was just that the code I was finding wasn't working correctly but I was able to figure it out.

```
'' The sheet is added here
Sheets.Add.Name = "Temp_Text_File"
'' Going through the code I think when you add a sheet it's automatically targetted, but this is a precaution -- makes "Temp_Text_File" the active sheet
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp_Text_File").Activate
'' Next three lines open and copy text file (not physically opened.... just opened to read)
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.GetFile(filePath)
f.Copy (filePath)
'' This paste method will start at range "A1"
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Thank you,

Jesse Smothermon

Comment: If the content of your txt file is separated by some character (comma, semicolon, ...) then you should use the `Workbooks.OpenText` method that the values get into the correct columns. (see my solution)

Comment: Yeah, that's actually why I chose your answer over mine, your answer is more flexible in the end